# UILabel not wrapping correctly after text change

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I'm working via the IB and have a UILabel that's stretched almost to the end of the layout. I have it set with Lines=2, because the max amount of lines it should take is 2. However if it's only 1 line long, I would like it to have a vertical justification of top.

Label settings in IB:

```
 Lines:2
 Line breaks: Word wrap
```

In code, in the viewDidLoad method I set the text of the UILabel. However as part of the functionality at a point the text must change. This is my code:

```
[_main_lbl1 setText:[myUI MAIN_TITLE]];  //Always only 1 line
[_main_lblsub1 setText:[myUI SUB_TITLE]]; //May be 1 or 2 lines
[_main_lblsub1 sizeToFit];  //Causes vertical alignment (I believe)
```

Whenever I change the text and rerun sizeToFit, the text wrapping becomes totally messed up. Instead of reaching almost the end of the UILabel as set up in the IB, in some cases the text will wrap at little more than half the distance, in some cases it doesn't wrap at all.

Image of layout in IB:

[image: Label in IB]

Image of resulting label in simulator:

[image: Image of resulting label in simulator]

In the first label it seems to be working ok, the second label doesn't wrap at all.

Is there anything I have to do to keep the text wrapping when changing the UILabel text? Anything else I'm missing?

***Note***: Updated question to include more detail and pics.

Thanks

Comment: So you want it to wrap, and it just wraps at the wrong place? Or you don't want it to wrap?

Comment: Please show some pic and code you have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything special. It will automatically wrap the text to fit when you change it. Otherwise the text would run out of the text labels bounds (which is not what you want). Your problem is that sizeToFit permanently changes the frame of the label. It makes it as small as possible while still showing the text. You are having it resize its frame to the original text and then you are changing the text so it is no longer sized properly. You should reset the frame back to it's original, change the text, and finally call size to fit again.

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.originalFrame =  self.mainLabelSub1.frame;
```

Then in viewWillAppear:

```
self.mainLabel1.frame = self.originalFrame;
self.mainLabel1.text = @"New Text";
```

**Note:**
A good way to see the borders of the text label to get an idea for the wrapping potential is to temporary set the background of the label to something like magentaColor that stands out.

Comment: Hey, add a little more detail to the question. Thanks

Comment: I think I know what your problem is. I updated my answer appropriately. Basically sizeToFit permanently changes the label's frame for the text in it at the time. You need to reset it before changing the text and resizing again.

Comment: Reset the frame? How is that done? So basically the first time it is run I could create a frame, and just reapply this same frame after the text is updated?

Comment: Ya by reset I mean just set it again. In code you could store the "original" frame before you call -sizeToFit. Then each time to change the text you set the frame to the "original" frame and call -sizeToFit again.

Comment: Do you happen to have code for this? I'm still kinda new to iOS dev.

Comment: You can add a property to the view controller that owns your text field; lets call it "originalFrame". In the -viewDidLoad method set the property equal to the `_main_lblsub1.frame`. Then when you go to change the text first do `_main_lblsub1.frame = self.originalFrame;`

Comment: This did fix the wrapping, but in labels that have only 1 line of text the vertical alignment is centered. Is there any way to get it to align to the top?

Comment: Set the contentVerticalAlignment to UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're using sizeToFit.  Which stretches the label out to fit the text.  If you need to change the size you can use:

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 9999);  // 999 means it can be as tall as you like

CGSize textSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                         constrainedToSize:maxSize];
label.size = textSize;
```

Comment: This will stop it from wrapping at all. He seems to be unhappy with how it is wrapping, not that it is wrapping at all.

Comment: Hi, added a little more detail to the question. As drewag says, I actually want it to wrap.

Comment: Updated my answer based on new images.